# coxph : "**Error in if (any(infs)) warning(paste("Loglik converged before variable ", : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"**

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am doing a Multi-touch Attribution problem using `coxph()` function. Its a large dataset with around 1 million data but currently I am running a subset of ~100000.
I have removed all the missing values from my data. I am getting an error

```
Error in if (any(infs)) warning(paste("Loglik converged before variable ", 
 :missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Here is the Cox Function :

```
SurvObj <- Surv(Final_Data$NormalizedStartTime,Final_Data$NormalizedEndTime,event = Final_Data$Converted)

model2 <- coxph(SurvObj ~  Clicks + RFR + Impressions + Other + `Site-ID` + `Creative-ID`, data = Final_Data1)
```

Thanks in Advance for the help :)
[The Error and the Summary of Final_Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35y7d.png)

Comment: You should rather build the Surv-object inside the formula. Building it as you do looses the connection to the `Final_Data` object during latter processing. Also a dangerous practice to leave dashes (which are minus signs) inside variable names. Much better to use dots or underscores so you don't need to quote in formulas.

Answer (score 4):

The line above, "Loglik" and so on, is meant to give information about a dubious test, where loglik converges beforehandedly.
The full line, when produced correctly, should be something akin to the following:

"Loglik converged before variable 100; beta may be infinite."

And it is produced by the following code in the agreg.Rnw
https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/survival/noweb/agreg.Rnw?diff_format=c&sortdir=down&sortby=author&revision=11529&root=survival&view=markup

```
if (any(infs))
        warning(paste("Loglik converged before variable ",
                      paste((1:nvar)[infs],collapse=","),
                  "; beta may be infinite. "))
```

From here we can see that the any() would expect the infs to be a number. If infs is NaN, the function will not work.

The inner part functions like this:

```
paste("Loglik converged before variable ",
                      paste((1:1)[NaN],collapse=","),
                  "; beta may be infinite. ")
[1] "Loglik converged before variable  NA ; beta may be infinite. "
```

so this part of the function would run, if it could get to the inner part. But it does not, since evaluating

```
infs <- NaN
if (any(infs))
warning(paste("Loglik converged before variable ",
                      paste((1:nvar)[infs],collapse=","),
                  "; beta may be infinite. "))

Error in if (any(infs)) warning(paste("Loglik converged before variable ",  : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

the exact error you had. The infs variable is generated before, via infs <- abs(agfit$u %*% var). And the agfit is produced via .Call(Cagfit4.....), so the problem is in the underlying C code for the function.

For some of my data, both the agfit$u and agfit$imat are NaNs. The $u and $imat are generated from

```
u2 =    SET_VECTOR_ELT(rlist, 1, allocVector(REALSXP, nvar));
u = REAL(u2);
```

and

```
PROTECT(imat2 = allocVector(REALSXP, nvar*nvar));
nprotect =1;
if (NAMED(covar2)>0) {
    PROTECT(covar2 = duplicate(covar2)); 
    nprotect++;
    }
covar= dmatrix(REAL(covar2), nused, nvar);
imat = dmatrix(REAL(imat2),  nvar, nvar);
```

respectively, in the agfit4 C code. I am not that good in C so I cannot say what the problem is in the C code area. It could be a bug or then the Cox function is not usable for your data or both. Nevertheless, something should be done to this, since I've seen others asking about this error too. But unfortunately I am not skilled enough to fix this, I only can point to the problem and holler "hey! somebody else pls take care of this" :-).

My possible solutions would be:

1) check if your data is usable with the Cox function at all (e.g. if you have 2000 cases of 0 and 2 cases of 1, the Cox function may not be suitable anyway, and the error is suggesting you find another way for the analysis :-) )

2) modify the code to do the any(infs) evaluation via removing the NAs, resulting in FALSE and skipping the error via the following:
    if (any(infs, na.rm=T)) (could screw up the code, tho)

3) fix the C code so that the agfit4 does not produce NaNs in the output object. (only for the skilled, not me)

Comment: How do we modify the code to do the evaluation via removing NAs? My data is usable with the Cox function but am still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. Turns out one of my variables had infinite values in it. Problem solved once I replaced these values

Comment: what do you mean when you say "variables had infinte values in it" ? I am currently facing this same problem, but am unable to find a solution.

Comment: It means one of the predictor variables had one (or more) of its elements take an infinite value. This can happen for example when in the process of calculating that variable one of the elements was divided by 0